# Performing Left Join on two CSV files in Apache Beam Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

For my practice I tried joining two CSV in Apache Beam on a condition with no success. Also checked multiple posts, however nothing works.

I have two CSV input file, tab separated, and I want to extract Column A, C from Primary file and Column A from secondary file.
Join condition will be Master.A = Secondary.B

Master:
[image: Master]
Secondary:
[image: Secondary]

I tried creating different Pcollection for both of them and do not know how to proceed further.
Again, this (CSV join) is one of the condition. How will I deal when it's a combination of multiple files (CSV-JSON-xyz)?

Answer (score 0):

To join your collections, you will want to extract the join columns as keys and then use the [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.transforms.util.html?highlight=cogroupbykey#apache_beam.transforms.util.CoGroupByKey) transform. The output of that transform is one element per key that contains the join results from each input.

Comment: did the same, but the output is nested. any pointers to get the output in relational format?